# IE Automation of HTML/Java Form to Oracle Database: Input data does not save to database

Tags: html, excel, oracle, vba

I have created VBA code which opens a web form to an Oracle Database, manipulates the page so that all pertinent text boxes are visible, and input the values from an Excel spreadsheet.  This all works well and as expected.

When I submit the form, I get a congratulatory message advising that my data has been accepted and is updated.  But when I go to view this data, it is missing.  When I manually update the webpage the data updates as expected.

Any thoughts on what this behavior stems from and how to overcome it?

It is on an intranet, so I will not be able to share the URL. I personally think that the the webpage differentiates between how I have entered the data and when it has been typed in.

```
x = 1
For Each i In Range("dailyCV")
    IE.document.all(col_1.Item(x)).Value = i
    IE.document.all(col_2.Item(x)).Value = col_5(x)
    x = x + 1
Next i
```

Is there a way to have VBA mimic the actual typing of the numbers, or an even easier way of handling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the issue was that the input values were not firing off the function that checked the validity of the input.  This function then feeds the data into an array that ultimately is saved to the database.  I was clued in when I tried typing a decimal or character into the field; they automatically changed to zero.  The offending snippet of code is below:

```
$('.allowedValues').keyup(function(){
    var n = this.value;
    if(this.value.length >0 && !(isNaN(this.value)) && !(n.indexOf(".")>0) ){
    //Nothing
    }else {
        this.value="0";
    }
});
```

Firing this function allows the data to be saved to the database once it is submitted.  I altered the code from above in the following way.  The code then worked as expected.

```
x = 1
For Each i In Range("dailyCV")
    IE.document.all(col_1.Item(x)).Value = i
    Call IE.document.parentWindow.execScript("$('.allowedValues').keyup()", "JavaScript")
    IE.document.all(col_2.Item(x)).Value = col_5(x)
    Call IE.document.parentWindow.execScript("$('.allowedValues').keyup()", "JavaScript")
    x = x + 1
Next i
```

I found the function by using the 'Inspect Elements' feature of Google Chrome, and inspecting the Event Listeners that were listed when I inspected the element of the text box.